# column alias oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-xe

This seems so simple but I can't understand how do I do this query:
I have a table users like this:

```
user_id | name | role
1       | abc  | a
2       | lol  | b
3       | f    | c
```

and a table usersprojects (with user and project PKs)

```
projectid | userid
1         | 1
1         | 2
2         | 2
2         | 3
```

How could I select all users columns and also a boolean column alias "assigned" to project "1"

I would like a result like this:

```
user_id | name | role | assigned
1       | abc  | a    | true
2       | lol  | b    | true
3       | f    | c    | false
```

The query wouldn't be something like this:

```
 Select user_id ,name, role,
  (users.user_id in (Select user_id from usersprojects where projectid=1)
    ) assigned;
```

But it doesn't work... what is the right way to do this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    user_id, name, role,
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UsersProjects up #
               WHERE up.user_id = u.user_id) > 0 
         THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END assigned
FROM Users u
```

Comment: This solved, I only needed to do one change: "...WHERE up.user_id = u.user_id AND up.projectid = 1 ..."

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT u.user_id ,name, role, NVL(projectId, 0) assigned
 FROM users u LEFT JOIN userprojects up ON (u.user_id = up.userid)
```

Comment: This produces duplicate user records when they are assigned to more than one project, which may not be what the OP wanted.

Comment: exactly, I tried it and it shows all users and which projects they're assigned...

Answer (score 0):

You need a left outer join. Keep in mind that there is no `boolean` data type in Oracle.